# What type of NoSQL database has better performances for inserting non-structured data?

Tags: performance, insert, nosql, scalability

I found 4 types of NoSQL :

- Document (ex: MongoDB, CouchDB)
- Column (ex: Cassandra, HBase)
- Key-value (ex: Redis, Memcached)
- Graph (ex: Neo4j)

Which of this type is more suitable for **inserting a lot of** non-structured data ? (scalability)

The database should be able to **insert thousands of requests per second** (coordinates, dates, names or id).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Tarantool** http://tarantool.org for the same scenario. It is capable to process up to 120K write operations per second.